# Hyperledger Composer Incompatible versions error and the versions are the same

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

Executing:

```
composer network ping -n calma-network -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.8.0) is not compatible with client (0.11.0)
Command failed
```

The versions look the same:

```
composer -v

composer-cli                   v0.11.0
composer-admin                 v0.11.0
composer-client                v0.11.0
composer-common                v0.11.0
composer-runtime-hlf           v0.11.0
composer-runtime-hlfv1         v0.11.0
```

Comment: Please refer to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850195/composer-runtime-0-19-13-is-not-compatible-with-client-0-20-0/51946383#51946383) Hope this will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rebooting Hyperledger Fabric (stopFabric.sh, teardownFabric.sh and startFabric.sh) solves the error.

Comment: Please, accept your answer as the correct one, since it helped solve the problem

Comment: didn't work for me

Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.5) is not compatible with client (0.19.4)

Comment: Rebooting did not  work for me as it picked up from the same package file.I added the version manually with @x.x.x (x being the version number) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. The fix for me was to first find the location of composer by typing `which composer` in the terminal. Then I manually deleted the directory containing it `rm -rf /PATH/OF/COMPOSER`. Then run `npm install -g composer-cli@latest`. After type `composer -v` to verify new version.

Comment: Thanks.  I had older runtime being reported (0.19.13) when I tried to run network ping, even though composer -V was reporting 0.20.0.   Physically deleting all the node_modules and reinstalling fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error but differently:

> Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.11.1) is not
>   compatible with client (0.10.1)

OP had old runtime and new client, but in my case, I had new runtime and old client. I was not able to solve the problem by Rebooting Hyperledger fabric. Instead, I updated composer-rest-server and it worked.

```
sudo npm install -g composer-rest-server
```

**Note:** After rebooting hyperledger fabric, you need to re-deploy the chaincode or say `bna` file in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue

```
trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.16.5) is not compatible with client (0.16.3)
```

This was because composure had newer version than composure-playground. To fix this

- Shutdown the composer
- `npm install -g composer-playground`

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem and found an issue ..

### Problem

while executing below command got an error
composer-rest-server -c admin@airlinev8 -p 3000

Nitishs-MacBook-Pro:fabric-dev-servers nitishbhushan$ composer-rest-server -c admin@airlinev8 -p 3000
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.9) is not compatible with client (0.19.8)
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.9) is not compatible with client (0.19.8)
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.9) is not compatible with client (0.19.8)

### solution

step 1: check version of composer-cli and composer-rest-server
composer-cli - 0.19.9
composer-rest-server - 0.19.8

step2: install latest version of composer-rest-server
npm install composer-rest-server -g

After this step, I ran the command again and it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the same version everywhere.In your case if it is 0.8.0 then make everything same with the command as below.

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.8.0 --save
npm install -g composer-admin@0.8.0 --save
npm install -g composer-common@0.8.0 --save
```

...like wise.

You can also try with the following.

```
sudo npm install -g composer-rest-server@0.8.0
```

cheers!