# Try to update hyperledger-composer version,but still not compatible with the client version

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I just a new beginner of Hyperledger Composer.So I try to deploy REST server using Docker by following this guide

[Deploying the REST server for a business network](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html)

Then when i run docker, it show this error on `docker logs`

```
docker logs rest
0|composer | WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
0|composer | WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
0|composer | Discovering types from business network definition ...
0|composer | D0831 07:04:36.180952003      24 env_linux.c:66]             Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used
0|composer | D0831 07:04:37.574385287      24 env_linux.c:66]             Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used
0|composer | Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.11.3) is not compatible with client (0.11.2)
0|composer | It will be retried for the next request.
0|composer | Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.11.3) is not compatible with client (0.11.2)
0|composer | Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.11.3) is not compatible with client (0.11.2)
0|composer |     at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:696:34)
PM2        | App [composer-rest-server] with id [0] and pid [24], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
PM2        | App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
```

So i try to update the version by following on this guide on the same doc

[Updating Hyperledger Composer](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/updating-composer.html)

But after I stop/reboot fabric, redeploy the chaincode again and run the docker, the error still exist.

Can anyone please tell me what i've missing?

Note: I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565506/hyperledger-composer-incompatible-versions-error-and-the-versions-are-the-same) too but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i've solve the problem. I remove all docker image and start new fabric to download image again,and it works!!

```
docker rmi $(docker images  -q)
```