# Composer runtime (0.19.13) is not compatible with client (0.20.0)

Tags: hyperledger-composer

composer network ping --card admin@blockchaingrades-network
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.13) is not compatible with client (0.20.0)
Command failed

Comment: You need to provide more detail about how you have arrived at this situation and what your environment is.

Answer (score 2):

either downgrade your composer-rest-server version to version 0.19.13 (npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.13) or update your composer-cli version to version 0.20.0 (npm install -g composer-rest-server@0.20)

Answer (score 0):

upgrading runtime to 0.20.0 may not be enough. I faced the same situation - i upgraded everything to 0.20.0 version but i still had this error. What worked for me was i had to delete all docker containers with command with command:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

then i run startFabric.sh script, created archive, installed and started network, imported card and pinged network to check if it works. I recommend you to use stopFabric --> teardownFabric --> teardownAllDocker scripts then remove docker containers with command above, (you can also reset docker with `systemctl restart docker` command and then start everything again. In my case it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As your error says you are using the composer client version 0.20.0 that is incompatible with your composer runtime version 0.19.13.

If you run `composer -v` you will see *v0.20.0*

A solution is to uninstall the version 0.20.0 of your client and to reinstall the client 0.19.13. You can do this with the following commands:

1. npm uninstall -g composer-cli
2. npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.13

Worked for me (same error with client version 0.19.15 and runtime version 0.19.12)